# Find a continuous function such that satisfies an equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find, if there are, continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow ]0,+\infty[$ such that

$[f(x)]^2=\int_{0}^{x}[f(t)]^2 \dfrac{\sin t}{2-\cos t} dt + 1$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

How can I do? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous, then the right hand side above differentiable (by the fundamental theorem of calculus), thus we can differentiate: $$2f(x)f'(x) = f(x)^2 \frac{\sin x}{2 - \cos x} \,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\, f'(x) = \frac{\sin x}{ 4 - 2\cos x} f(x).$$ It is also clear from the formula that $f(0) = \pm 1$ but since we want $f$ to take positive values, we must have $f(0) = 1$. This is a initial value problem for $f$ which can be solved using basic techniques from differential equation. Are you aware of these solution techniques?

Comment: Yes, it is in the form y'+a(x)y=0. Thanks a lot !